# Losses in solar electric system?

Tags: solar-energy, efficiency

In a typical, simple solar power collector system (solar panels > battery > electric motor), what losses can be expected for a rated wattage of the panels to the charging of the battery?

If a panel is rated to provide 200W (ideal conditions considered) would there be any losses in the wiring to the battery, a few percent? Are there any other losses I should be aware of? (Ignoring the variability of sunshine & atmospherics)

Comment: That greatly depends on the matching of the panels with the battery and the type of solar battery charger used.

Comment: What types of charger do you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rated power of the solar panel is under standard test conditions (STC) that don't usually exist in the real world. The panel is kept at 25C, and the incident light is 1000W per square meter. As you can imagine, the panel does not want to stay at 25C when it is getting hit with 1000W per square meter, so it has to be cooled during the test, or, the test must be very brief so that it doesn't have time to heat up.

Perhaps in some cool but sunny place this can be achieved in the real world. But in many places it is impossible in the field.

Many panels also come with a more realistic rating called NOCT  (normal operating cell temperature) rating. This is the output when cell temperature is 47.5C and incident light power is 800W per square meter. In reality the panel temperature will vary based on location and installation details (such as how exposed the back side of the panel is to circulating air).

To sum up, assuming constant light conditions, temperature is by far the biggest factor in power generation. In general, when cell temperature goes up, the Vmpp and output power go down.

The inverter or charge controller also has losses. Most grid tie inverters seem to be 90 or 95 percent efficient (roughly). Charge controllers vary widely. I would say that 80 to 95 percent may be the range.

If you direct connect the panel to the battery with no charge controller, then you also have the problem of the panel not being at its MPP (maximum power point). This may be OK for panels with 36 cells and a 12V lead acid battery (as long as you avoid over-charge). But in some cases the solar panel output will be greatly reduced if the battery voltage is not a good match for the number of cells in the panel.

There are losses in the wiring, but these can be kept under control by using larger diameter wires.

Comment: Thanks very much; the NOCT rating, is something I needed. Also, the estimate for the controller. So, if the panels are connected to the battery via a solar charge controller, would this ensure compatibility and the panels’ to be at their MPP?

Comment: You at least need a charge controller to make sure you don't over-charge your batteries. And if the panel is not a good match to the battery, then you need an MPPT charge controller to adjust for the mis-match.

Comment: Alright. Can you please comment what are the parameters for the match-up of panel & bat - is it voltage and amps only? Or something else too

Comment: The MPPT voltage of the panel should be close to the normal voltage of the battery. The classic match up is for a panel with 36 solar cells and a 12V lead acid battery. Also 18 cells with a 6 Volt battery or 72 cells with a 24 V battery. This combination works reasonably well without MPPT, but you can  and will still over-charge the battery if you don't use a simple (non MPPT) charge controller. In your case, with the motor, maybe a charge controller would not be needed as long as the motor can be relied upon to turn on when voltage is high enough.

Comment: If you are using lithium chemistry (LiIon, Lipo or LFP) I would suggest just get an MPPT charge controller to be safe and modern and efficient.

Comment: Thanks; then the system with MPPT charge controller is a very reasonable choice. The batteries are AGM Lead acid

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**: Static losses are typically 4% in the inverter, and 14% for the balance of system. There is also loss as a function of module temperature, typically about 0.5% per degC above 25. Thus at 25 degC assume losses of 17.4 %.

---

[PV Watts](https://pvwatts.nrel.gov/pvwatts.php), a tool for estimating annual output of solar photovoltaic systems (developed by the U.S. National Renewable Energy Lab) provides details of the sources of loss in a PV system, and typical values:

| Category | Default Value (%) |
| --- | --- |
| Soiling | 2 |
| Shading | 3 |
| Snow | 0 |
| Mismatch | 2 |
| Wiring | 2 |
| Connections | 0.5 |
| Light-induced Degradation | 1.5 |
| Nameplate Rating | 1 |
| Age | 0 |
| Availability | 3 |
| **TOTAL** | **14** |

Note that the total is not the sum, but the product, according to this formula:

> [image]

The [technical manual](https://pvwatts.nrel.gov/pvwatts.php) provides details on each of these, and also explains two additional categories of losses:

> The Inverter's DC-to-AC Conversion Efficiency is a separate input under Advanced Parameters with a default value of 96%. Do not include inverter conversion losses in the system loss percentage.
>
> PVWatts® calculates temperature-related losses as a function of the cell temperature, so you should not include temperature loss in the system loss percentage.

The temperature coefficients are a function of the module type. Default values are provided in the table below, but this information will be in the specification for the modules you're using. The reference temperature is 25 degC.

| Module type | Temperature coefficient |
| --- | --- |
| Standard | -0.47 % / degC |
| Premium | -0.35 % / degC |
| Thin film | -0.20 % / degC |

Comment: Great! It would take me so much longer to find it as clearly. So, if the system does not use inverter but rather feeds the DC from panel via solar charger to the battery (i.e. in a vehicle), would the losses then amount to a 14% loss + temperature correction?

Comment: @ivanantuns yes. Of course you can adjust some values in the table to your specific situation (soiling, shading, snow, etc), and wiring and connections you can measure directly, but 14% seems to be a reasonable overall assumption.

Comment: You will almost never have 86% of your rated power. The typical relationship between STC and NOCT is more like 75%.

Comment: Ok, but, I meant 86% considering only the losses mentioned; excluding temperature and charge controller losses? So, the gross 14%-ish loss, then the controller deficiency (0.8-0.95 as a factor, mentioned in other answer), minus temperature correction (assuming, say, 45 deg Celsius with standard module temp coefficient) would give a rough conservative estimate of 66%?